# Inserting vertical rows in TableLayout

Tags: android

I'm trying to add rows to a `TableLayout` in Android and the orientation property doesn't seem to work.  Basically I need to create a `TableRow`, add multiple `TextView`s to it, and the add to the `TableLayout` and have the `TextView`s stacked vertically instead of horizontally.

The XML looks like this:

```
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/mylayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TableRow  android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <TextView android:text="Test1"></TextView>
            <TextView android:text="Test2"></TextView>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

This seems like it should work, but the TextViews end up stacked left to right.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem.I made a `RelativeLayout` and I am  programmatically adding vertical orientation `LinearLayout` to it for each vertical row.I keep a handle to the control ID of the last inserted `LinearLayout` and insert the new one to the right of that ID. Feels a bit kludgy, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

```
We can do by inserting TableLayout inside TableRow,like this.


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/mylayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TableRow  android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <TableLayout android:id="@+id/mylayout1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView android:text="Test1"></TextView>
            <TextView android:text="Test2"></TextView>
            </TableLayout>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
        <TextView android:text="Test1"></TextView>
        <TextView android:text="Test2"></TextView>
```

to:

```
        <TextView android:text="Test1" android:layout_column="0"></TextView>
        <TextView android:text="Test2" android:layout_column="0"></TextView>
```

See the documentation `TableLayout` ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html ) it says

> Cells must be added to a row in increasing column order, both in code and XML. Column numbers are zero-based. If you don't specify a column number for a child cell, it will autoincrement to the next available column. If you skip a column number, it will be considered an empty cell in that row. See the TableLayout examples in ApiDemos for examples of creating tables in XML.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Thomas.  layout_column is not a property of TextView, unless I'm missing something.  I tried programmatically setting the column by doing this, but still looks the same...  TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
  TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
  tv1.setText("Test1");
  tv2.setText("Test2");
  tv1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0));
  tv2.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0));

Comment: Are you positive you are not making a typing error? You can see an example here: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html

Comment: I saw that example.  The column number does work but only for organizing the data horizontally. I need the columns to grow vertically.  I'm adding data top to bottom, 1 row at a time.

Comment: Well technically you're trying to add two things to one row in a vertical fashion. Have you tried adding two rows each with one TextView in it?

Comment: The problem is, I don't have the data for the 2nd column on the 1st row when I'm filling the 1st row in (it will be populated dynamically in a loop).  If I add 2 rows each with one TextView, they're populated vertically.  When I try to add the 3rd vertical row of the table in column 1, it's on the 3rd row and not back on the 1st to the right of the very first TextView.

Comment: According to the documentation that comes down to specifying layout_column. They say if a number is not used it is considered skipped. Unfortunately I can't really tinker with this at the moment, I am in front of an android dev environment.

Comment: Yeah, I think based on what they say, you can change the column the View is displayed in, but that only helps if you want to change the horizontal position of the View.  I need the Row itself to be vertical so the elements are added on top of each other, rather than left to right.  The orientation property seems to be for this purpose, but it doesn't look to have any affect at all on the layout.  I'm toggling back and forth in the layout editor with Outlines turned on and the Row is always horizontal, no matter what the orientation is set to on either the table or the row.

Comment: The documentation lists the orientation attribute but most of the text makes it sound very strongly that you can't work with it the way you're desiring. For example this excerpt `Cells must be added to a row in increasing column order, both in code and XML`

Comment: Hmmm, well that stinks.  My app needs to have a set of fixed attributes down the left side of the screen and a variable number of items to be compared left-to-right.

Answer (score 1):

Create a LinearLayout with vertical orientation and have your text views inside it. Then add this LinearLayout to the TableRow

```
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/mylayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TableRow  android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
             <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:orientation="vertical" >
                     <TextView android:text="Test1"></TextView>
                     <TextView android:text="Test2"></TextView>
             </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: What's the benefit of having the `<TableLayout />` and `<TableRow />`?